# python flask display image on a html page

Tags: python, html, flask, flash-message

I am trying to pass a filename of an image and render it on a template,
Although I am passing the actual name through it does not display on the page

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
@app.route('/start', methods=['GET','POST'])
def start():
person_to_show = 'tim'
profilepic_filename = os.path.join(people_dir, person_to_show, "img.jpg")
return render_template('start.html',profilepic_filename  =profilepic_filename )
```

For example: profilepic_filename = /data/tim/img.jpg
I have tried

```
{{profilepic_filename}}
<img src="{{ url_for('data', filename='tim/img.jpg') }}"></img>
```

And I have also tried

```
<img src="{{profilepic_filename}}"></img>
```

Neither of which worked

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I have created `people_photo` in `static` folder and placed an image named `shovon.jpg`. From the `application.py` I passed the image as variable to template and showed it using `img` tag in the template.

In `application.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os

PEOPLE_FOLDER = os.path.join('static', 'people_photo')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = PEOPLE_FOLDER

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def show_index():
    full_filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'shovon.jpg')
    return render_template("index.html", user_image = full_filename)
```

In `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{ user_image }}" alt="User Image">
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Did anyone else have trouble getting this to work?  pycharm tells me `Process finished with exit code 0` but `localhost:5000` isn't showing any images

Comment: @frank, `localhost:5000`is available as long as the program remains in  running state. There might be something that stopped the program and you got `Process finished with exit code 0`.

Comment: How can we display an image from S3 links? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @vinitkantrod, it is not in the scope of this question. It will be better if you can create a new question regarding S3 bucket image usage in Flask. I think future readers will be benefited.

Comment: is there a way to use a sub-folder instead of the static folder and pass through the `local ressource` error?

Comment: add app.run(host='0.0.0.0') to end of the file to start this as a server

Comment: Somehow the method in this answer by @arshovon did not work for me but I followed the method in this other blog which worked for me: https://kanchanardj.medium.com/how-to-add-images-to-html-in-a-flask-app-4dbcc92e3aeb