# Flask: 127.0.0.1 - - "GET /home/n/templates/tree.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Tags: python, flask

Flask newbie here, trying to show an image through Flask.

==============================================

#### ~/server.py

==============================================

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, g, redirect, Response, send_from_directory

tmpl_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'templates')
print(tmpl_dir)
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=tmpl_dir)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print(request.args)
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

==============================================

#### ~/templates/index.html:

==============================================

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Text-to-Image Synthesis</h1>
    <img src="/home/n/templates/tree.jpg" width="700" height="500">
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Things I've tried:

1. send_from_directory()
2. render_template("index.html", **context)
3. Literally copying the code from [python flask display image on a html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46785507/python-flask-display-image-on-a-html-page)

The image `tree.jpg` is in the proper directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps,

1. Move `tree.jpg` to static folder
2. As per your project structure, static path for image should be `~/static/tree.jpg`
3. Then use,

   `<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='tree.jpg')}}" />`

Comment: Tried this, and the image shows up!  I still get `ImmutableMultiDict([])` though...  What does this error mean?

Comment: @platonicity can you please show stacktrace ?