# How to display images of mnist digits dataset on a website using flask

Tags: machine-learning, flask

The project involves displaying the dataset on website. I did it in jupyter notebook using matplot lib.plt But I have to display the images on website using flask

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46785507/python-flask-display-image-on-a-html-page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serve static files in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646822/how-to-serve-static-files-in-flask)