# build jinja url_for with jinja variables

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to server images from a folder that is a subfolder of `'static'` in my Python 3.7 Flask project.
I render the template using `render_template('gallery.html', data=data)` where `data` is a list of file paths. Gallery.html is a 3xn grid of pictures.

I tried `<img src="{{ url_for({{data[0]}}) }}">` but that doesn't do anything. Just using `{{data[0]}}` in the template displays the filepath, though.

Something that also didn't work:

```
def gallery():
   data = get_files() # returns filenames in a list
   render_template('gallery.html', data=data)
```

Template:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='path/to/folder/{{data[0]}}' }}" >
```

How do I build the filepath and use them in a html `<img>` attribute with `url_for()`, so that my images are loaded correctly?

Comment: What the rendered do you expect to get ?

Comment: I want to get a rendered gallery, like a 3xn grid, if that is what you mean?

Comment: Try this
<img src="static/img/{{data[0]}}" > BTW
see similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46785507/python-flask-display-image-on-a-html-page/46794505

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution for me was:

```
{% for image in data %}
    <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/gallery/' + image) }}" alt="">
{% endfor %}
```

The variable doesn't need any brackets or quotes.